# How to create smooth VBA animation through PowerPoint VBA code--screen refresh?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm creating a puzzle game in PowerPoint, and I'm running into an issue when it comes to a VBA macro. I'm trying to get shape outlines to "flash" the team color randomly (while making a sound each time it flashes), so when the player hits a buzzer, it stops. The code is successful, but when in use the visuals lag significantly--the sound works with no lag.

I've tried a few different approaches such as For/Next loops, Do While/Loop, there doesn't seem to be an affect either way. The closest I have gotten in terms of research is that this may be slide refresh-related, but I haven't been able to figure out if that's true or not. Right now my delay is at .25 seconds, but if I extend it to 1 second, it works consistently. Unfortunately that isn't useful in this scenario because I'm attempting to create the element of randomization where the player doesn't know exactly where their color will stop; in other words, it needs to be fast.

Here's the main code and then the 2 references:

```
Sub YellowTeamPuzzleFlash()
Dim RandomNumber As Integer
Do While ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("YellowTeamLight").Visible = True
RandomNumber = Int((56 * Rnd) + 1)
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("PuzzleFlash" & RandomNumber).Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
delayTime3
playPing
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("PuzzleFlash" & RandomNumber).Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
Loop
End Sub
```

```
Sub delayTime3()

Dim PauseTime, Start
PauseTime = 0.25 ' Set duration in seconds
Start = Timer ' Set start time.
Do While Timer < Start + PauseTime
DoEvents ' Yield to other processes.
Loop

End Sub
```

```
Function playPing()

    Call PlaySound("C:\KTResources\Ping.wav", 0&, &H1 Or &H20000)

End Function
```

True PPT animations are still very smooth so I know this isn't hardware related, this seems entirely related to my usage of the code.